# Pidgin "Lost connection with server (out cb): Bad file descriptor"

Tags: pidgin, whatsapp

I tried to connect to whatsapp via Pidgin using this guide; http://topblog.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Install-WhatsApp-for-PC. I did **not** used the portable version.
After following each step, I got everything running, but I get the error "Lost connection with server (out cb): Bad file descriptor". I googled it, but couldn't find a satisfying answer because none of the found solutions did help.

I know it is a common error, but like I said, i was not able to fix it. Could somebody please help? 
Thanks in advance!

(Windows 7, 64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](http://davidgf.net/nightly/whatsapp-purple/win32/), try to download the latest dll. Current whatsapp version and the dll we use should be compatible.

Here is the latest [dll](http://davidgf.net/nightly/whatsapp-purple/win32/last-whatsapp.dll)

Comment: Thanks! I did that, but that didn't solve the problem. I keep getting the same error.